# No such file or directory "limits.h" when installing Pillow on Alpine Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, alpine-linux

I'm running alpine-linux on a Raspberry Pi 2.  I'm trying to install Pillow via this command:

```
pip install pillow
```

This is the output from the command:

```
Installing collected packages: pillow
Running setup.py install for pillow
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-gNq0WA/pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-nDKwei-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/OleFileIO.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageFileIO.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    copying PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    running egg_info
    writing Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching 'LICENSE' under directory 'docs'
    writing manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    copying PIL/OleFileIO-README.md -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL
    running build_ext
    building 'PIL._imaging' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -DNDEBUG -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -I/tmp/pip-build-gNq0WA/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _imaging.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/_imaging.o
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -DNDEBUG -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -I/tmp/pip-build-gNq0WA/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c outline.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/outline.o
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -DNDEBUG -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -I/tmp/pip-build-gNq0WA/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c libImaging/Bands.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Bands.o
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -DNDEBUG -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -I/tmp/pip-build-gNq0WA/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c libImaging/ConvertYCbCr.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/ConvertYCbCr.o
    In file included from _imaging.c:76:0:
    /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:19:20: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
    #include <limits.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    In file included from outline.c:20:0:
    /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:19:20: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
    #include <limits.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    In file included from libImaging/ImPlatform.h:10:0,
                    from libImaging/Imaging.h:14,
                    from libImaging/ConvertYCbCr.c:15:
    /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:19:20: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
    #include <limits.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    In file included from libImaging/ImPlatform.h:10:0,
                    from libImaging/Imaging.h:14,
                    from libImaging/Bands.c:19:
    /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:19:20: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
    #include <limits.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -DNDEBUG -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -I/tmp/pip-build-gNq0WA/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c libImaging/Draw.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Draw.o
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -DNDEBUG -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -I/tmp/pip-build-gNq0WA/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c libImaging/Filter.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Filter.o
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -DNDEBUG -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -I/tmp/pip-build-gNq0WA/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c libImaging/GifEncode.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/GifEncode.o
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -DNDEBUG -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -I/tmp/pip-build-gNq0WA/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c libImaging/LzwDecode.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/LzwDecode.o
    In file included from libImaging/ImPlatform.h:10:0,
                    from libImaging/Imaging.h:14,
                    from libImaging/Draw.c:35:
    /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:19:20: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
    #include <limits.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    In file included from libImaging/ImPlatform.h:10:0,
                    from libImaging/Imaging.h:14,
                    from libImaging/Filter.c:27:
    /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:19:20: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
    #include <limits.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    In file included from libImaging/ImPlatform.h:10:0,
                    from libImaging/Imaging.h:14,
                    from libImaging/GifEncode.c:20:
    /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:19:20: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
    #include <limits.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    In file included from libImaging/ImPlatform.h:10:0,
                    from libImaging/Imaging.h:14,
                    from libImaging/LzwDecode.c:31:
    /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:19:20: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
    #include <limits.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -DNDEBUG -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -I/tmp/pip-build-gNq0WA/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c libImaging/Offset.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Offset.o
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -DNDEBUG -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -I/tmp/pip-build-gNq0WA/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c libImaging/Quant.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Quant.o
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -DNDEBUG -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -I/tmp/pip-build-gNq0WA/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c libImaging/PcxDecode.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/PcxDecode.o
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -DNDEBUG -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -I/tmp/pip-build-gNq0WA/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c libImaging/RawEncode.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/RawEncode.o
    In file included from libImaging/ImPlatform.h:10:0,
                    from libImaging/Imaging.h:14,
                    from libImaging/Offset.c:18:
    /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:19:20: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
    #include <limits.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    In file included from libImaging/ImPlatform.h:10:0,
                    from libImaging/Imaging.h:14,
                    from libImaging/Quant.c:21:
    /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:19:20: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
    #include <limits.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    In file included from libImaging/ImPlatform.h:10:0,
                    from libImaging/Imaging.h:14,
                    from libImaging/PcxDecode.c:17:
    /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:19:20: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
    #include <limits.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    In file included from libImaging/ImPlatform.h:10:0,
                    from libImaging/Imaging.h:14,
                    from libImaging/RawEncode.c:21:
    /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:19:20: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
    #include <limits.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -DNDEBUG -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -I/tmp/pip-build-gNq0WA/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c libImaging/UnpackYCC.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/UnpackYCC.o
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -DNDEBUG -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -I/tmp/pip-build-gNq0WA/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c libImaging/ZipEncode.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/ZipEncode.o
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -DNDEBUG -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -I/tmp/pip-build-gNq0WA/pillow/libImaging -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c libImaging/BoxBlur.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/BoxBlur.o
    In file included from libImaging/ImPlatform.h:10:0,
                    from libImaging/Imaging.h:14,
                    from libImaging/UnpackYCC.c:17:
    /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:19:20: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
    #include <limits.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    In file included from libImaging/ImPlatform.h:10:0,
                    from libImaging/Imaging.h:14,
                    from libImaging/ZipEncode.c:18:
    /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:19:20: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
    #include <limits.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    In file included from libImaging/BoxBlur.c:1:0:
    /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:19:20: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
    #include <limits.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    Building using 4 processes
    gcc -shared -Wl,--as-needed build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/_imaging.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/decode.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/encode.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/map.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/display.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/outline.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/path.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Access.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/AlphaComposite.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Resample.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Bands.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/BitDecode.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Blend.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Chops.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Convert.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/ConvertYCbCr.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Copy.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Crc32.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Crop.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Dib.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Draw.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Effects.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/EpsEncode.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/File.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Fill.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Filter.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/FliDecode.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Geometry.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/GetBBox.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/GifDecode.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/GifEncode.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/HexDecode.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Histo.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/JpegDecode.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/JpegEncode.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/LzwDecode.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Matrix.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/ModeFilter.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/MspDecode.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Negative.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Offset.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Pack.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/PackDecode.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Palette.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Paste.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Quant.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/QuantOctree.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/QuantHash.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/QuantHeap.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/PcdDecode.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/PcxDecode.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/PcxEncode.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Point.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/RankFilter.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/RawDecode.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/RawEncode.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Storage.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/SunRleDecode.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/TgaRleDecode.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Unpack.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/UnpackYCC.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/UnsharpMask.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/XbmDecode.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/XbmEncode.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/ZipDecode.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/ZipEncode.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/TiffDecode.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Incremental.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Jpeg2KDecode.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Jpeg2KEncode.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/BoxBlur.o -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -ljpeg -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/PIL/_imaging.so
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/_imaging.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/decode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/encode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/map.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/display.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/outline.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/path.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Access.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/AlphaComposite.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Resample.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Bands.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/BitDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Blend.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Chops.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Convert.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/ConvertYCbCr.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Copy.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Crc32.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Crop.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Dib.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Draw.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Effects.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/EpsEncode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/File.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Fill.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Filter.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/FliDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Geometry.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/GetBBox.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/GifDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/GifEncode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/HexDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Histo.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/JpegDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/JpegEncode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/LzwDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Matrix.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/ModeFilter.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/MspDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Negative.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Offset.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Pack.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/PackDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Palette.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Paste.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Quant.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/QuantOctree.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/QuantHash.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/QuantHeap.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/PcdDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/PcxDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/PcxEncode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Point.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/RankFilter.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/RawDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/RawEncode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Storage.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/SunRleDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/TgaRleDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Unpack.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/UnpackYCC.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/UnsharpMask.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/XbmDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/XbmEncode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/ZipDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/ZipEncode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/TiffDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Incremental.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Jpeg2KDecode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/Jpeg2KEncode.o: No such file or directory
    gcc: error: build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/libImaging/BoxBlur.o: No such file or directory
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setup tools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-gNq0WA/pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-nDKwei-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-gNq0WA/pillow
```

I think this is probably the relevant section:

```
In file included from libImaging/BoxBlur.c:1:0:
    /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:19:20: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
    #include <limits.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
```

My research shows it's probably something with the header files.  I have installed these:

```
apk add py-configobj libusb py-pip python-dev gcc linux-headers
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install -U setuptools
pip install Cheetah
pip install pyusb
```

Comment: You might need to install the packages linux-kernel-headers and glibc-devel using your operating systems package manager

Comment: Ah, ok, thank you for the tip (and for formatting my question, sorry I'm new).  I checked Alpine-Linux repo and found linux-headers does seem to be the right package [link](http://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?pkgname=linux-headers&arch=armhf) but it doesn't look like that package contains limits.h.  I searched for glibc and no dice.  This did make me think of searching for limits.h.  [LINK](http://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?filename=limits.h&path=&pkgname=&arch=armhf) I tried the most obvious one: linux-rpi-dev, reran the installer but still no dice.  Same error

Answer (score 392, accepted):

Alpine Linux uses [musl libc](https://www.musl-libc.org/). You probably need to install `musl-dev`.

Comment: This did not work for me. I had to `apk add linux-headers` as Riccardo suggested.

Comment: Weird. This worked for me, but linux-headers did not. FROM python:3.6.6-alpine3.7

Comment: On Alpine 3.10.3, installing `musl-dev` did the trick.  Installing `linux-headers` did nothing.

Comment: On Alpine 3.18.3, installing `linux-headers` did the trick. Installing `musl-dev` did nothing.

Answer (score 113):

@zakaria answer is correct, but if you stumble upon

```
fatal error: linux/limits.h: No such file or directory
```

then you need the package `linux-headers` (notice the prefix `linux` before `limits.h`

```
apk add linux-headers
```

Comment: @guneysus FYI, adding `musl-dev` worked for me on `alpine 3.5`. Adding `linux-headers` was not sufficient (and I am not sure was necessary). As Riccardo says, it depends on name of the missing file.

Comment: @HRJ - I personally only needed `musl-dev`

Answer (score 47):

`limits.h` is located in `libc-dev`:

```
apk add libc-dev
```

Comment: This is the same for debian `stretch`

Comment: alpine uses musl and musl-dev instead

Comment: Acutally `musl-dev` is needed, it just happens that `libc-dev` has `musl-dev` as as dependency: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86_64/libc-dev

Answer (score 17):

I had a very similar problem with installing the Python library `regex` in Docker using the `python:3.6-alpine` image, for Alpine Linux >= 3.3.

```
pip install regex
```

I had to add `gcc` and `musl-dev` packages:

```
apk --no-cache add gcc musl-dev
```

Answer (score 4):

I've found some python packages fail to install via pip install but work if you install the associated alpine linux package. For example pip install uwsgi fails complaining about limits.h, but apk add uwsgi-python works fine. Suggest trying apk add py-pillow instead of pip install pillow.

Comment: It looks like they removed the python3 module from the alpine 3.3 repos. Do you have any clues why the builds fail anyway? Even when adding linux-headers and musl-dev I get lots of errors similar to this one:
core/utils.c: In function 'uwsgi_as_root':
    core/utils.c:344:7: error: implicit declaration of function 'unshare' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
       if (unshare(uwsgi.unshare)) {
           ^

Answer (score 2):

I faced this problem on `python:3.10-slim-buster` image.

Solved with `RUN apt-get --no-install-recommends install -y build-essential`

Although this won't work in Alpine, it may be useful to others who experience the same problem in other environments.

Comment: The minimal requirements you would actually need to solve this problem in `python:3.X-slim-buster` images (thus keeping the image actually as slim as possibile) are `gcc` and `libc6-dev` (which are part of Ubuntu's `build-essential`, together with `make`, `g++` and `dpkg-dev`) and you can install them through `RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install gcc libc6-dev -y --no-install-recommends --fix-missing`

Answer (score 0):

For alpine 3.18, i think the package that needed to solve this problem is linux-headers.
The reason because alpine 3.18 is using musl-dev 1.2.4. And linux/limits.h is not found at musl-dev 1.2.4, i found this after downloading musl-1.2.4 and try to extract it. At musl-dev 1.2.4 limits.h is inside of include directory so because it is different path if you install musl-dev, it will not solve this problem if you are using alpine 3.18.