# How can I fix gcc error when install multidict in alpine docker container?

Tags: python, gcc, alpine-linux

Q:
In my docker container, i use apline linux system which has been pre install gcc

apk info:

```
bash-4.4# apk info
....
gcc
```

But when I install multidict, failed by gcc error

```
bash-4.4# pip install multidict
Collecting multidict
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/96/5503ba866d8d216e49a6ce3bcb288df8a5fb3ac8a90b8fcff9ddcda32568/multidict-4.7.3.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: multidict
  Building wheel for multidict (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-79jceuft/multidict/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-79jceuft/multidict/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-57k4lw21 --python-tag cp37
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-79jceuft/multidict/
 ....
    /usr/local/include/python3.7m/Python.h:11:20: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
     #include <limits.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-79jceuft/multidict/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-79jceuft/multidict/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-lomj_vmk/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30873179/12521158) help?

Comment: I have been fix it

Comment: install musl-dev

Answer (score 6):

Simple fix was to add the below command in the dockerfile:

```
RUN apk --no-cache add gcc musl-dev
```

<sub>thanks to @Zosionlee for hint.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

pre install gcc and other environments.

e.g.

```
RUN apk update \
    && apk add --no-cache gcc git python3-dev musl-dev linux-headers  
    libc-dev  rsync zsh \
    findutils wget util-linux grep libxml2-dev libxslt-dev \
    &&  pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 1):

Encountered this issue, what fixed my problem without having to `sudo` install on the system:

```
$ pip install --upgrade pip setuptools-scm
```

I did this within a virtual environment too.